# Objective C - cannot set delegate error - Cannot find protocol declaration for 'myNSObjectClassDelegate'

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I just got started working with `delegates`.

from some reason I cannot do it, and I see errors.

I tried to do the next code on a new project and it was OK, but when i'm moving this code to my main project I have a few issues.

my `NSObject` class `.h`:

```
@protocol myNSObjectClassDelegate <NSObject>

@required
-(void)doSomething;

@end


@interface GeneralMethods : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,strong) id<myNSObjectClassDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

my `NSObject` class `.m`:

```
@synthesize delegate;

-(void)SomeMethod {
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(doSomething)]) {
        [delegate doSomething];
    }
}
```

my `UIViewController` `.h`

```
#import "GeneralMethods.h"

@interface view : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate,
                                   UINavigationControllerDelegate,
                                   UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                   myNSObjectClassDelegate>
```

The error is here at `.h` - `Cannot find protocol declaration for 'myNSObjectClassDelegate'`

my `UIViewController` `.m`

```
-(void)doSomething{
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT : I figure it out:
For some reason, at my `NSObject` class, if I'm moving the `#import myUIViewcontroller` after this:

```
@protocol myNSObjectClassDelegate <NSObject>

@required
-(void)doSomething;

@end
```

the problem solved.

Comment: not related to your question but you should better make your class and protocol names capitalised. It is a general convention

Comment: Generally speaking, you should not be maintaining a `strong` relationship to delegate protocols.

Answer (score 2):

We can't see all the code but after reading some more of the exchanges it looks like dependencies are maybe added out of order.  I recommend moving the protocol into its own file and #import'ing it to all the places that use it.  This way you definitely will be importing things in the order you expect.

In addition to that, the following property declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) id<myNSObjectClassDelegate> delegate;
```

Delegates should be declared as weak, not strong.

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) id<myNSObjectClassDelegate> delegate;
```

The reason is to avoid retain cycles/memory leaks.  Typically, though not always the relationship looks like this:

```
Parent Object (usually Controller) -----STRONG----->  Child (View often)
View Thing ----WEAK--------> delegate (actually the Parent Object)
```

Now if the relationship is STRONG both ways, releasing the parent from all who own it will not be sufficient to release it since its child also holds an owning relationship to it.

Also you can omit the:

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

Auto property synthesis renders this obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to import your `NSObject` class `.h.` file into your `UIViewController`'s `.h` file (or wherever you declare the protocol).  As it stands, you haven't imported the header that declares the protocol so your view controller has no way of knowing that it exists.

Ex:

```
#import "FileWithProtocol.h"

@interface MyClass <MyProtocol>

...

@end
```

Comment: I'm not sure - while he hasn't actually shown it, it's expected that the `.m` file for his view controller imports the corresponding `.h` file, which *does* contain the import for the protocol.

Comment: If he imports it in the implementation file, the header file still won't be able to find it.

Comment: Right, I'm saying - the header file should import the protocol. (Which it already seems to, in his code snippet.) And the implementation file should import the header. OP's class names are confusing, but it seems like `view.h` should import `GeneralMethods.h`, and `view.m` should import `view.h`. But it seems like he should already be doing this...

Answer (score -1):

In the view controller .h file, try adding this line:

```
@protocol MyNSObjectClassDelegate;
```

before

```
@interface ...
```

Comment: The compiler is still going to warn about an undeclared protocol.

Comment: But he was already importing the protocol file in his code snippets, in #import "GeneralMethods.h". Anyway, he solved it...